# Why does this vector throw a bad allocation exception?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

Why does this seemingly innocent function throw a bad allocation exception for `noUrls=300,000,000`?

```cpp
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>

    void generateUrls(int noUrls)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> urls;
        urls.resize(noUrls); //this always works
        std::size_t i = 0;
        std::string url = "abcdefghijklmnop";
        
        urls[i] = "https://www." + url + ".com/home/index";
        i++;
    
        while (std::next_permutation(url.begin(), url.end()) && (i < noUrls))
        {
            urls[i] = "https://www." + url + ".com/home/index"; //this where it throws
            i++;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        generateUrls(100000000);
        //do something with the result
        return 0;
    }
```

Why?

**Clues:**

- `noUrls=300,000,000` is not causing an overflow, my platform's maximum int size of 2,147,483,647
- The resulting vector will be about 12GB large
- My system has 8GB physical RAM, but a page file size of another 16GB, so would have expected it to just stick some of the vector in the page file if it runs out of physical RAM. (A stupid assumption?)

Comment: Why are you doing `(i+1) < noUrls` instead of `i < noUrls`?

Comment: That does appear to be a typo yeah, hah, but a moot point since it never gets anywhere near there!

Comment: `generateUrls(int noUrls);` is not a function call. The program does nothing at all. Please post a real [mcve].

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do because this is an illustrative toy. But think about ways of processing the URLs one at a time rather than generating 100,000,0000 (>25% of the internet). If you do need to hold data about that number of sites consider some database technology.   MySQL? MongoDB? Both will easily hold those sorts of volumes of data on even a modest machine.

Comment: @Persixty thanks for your amendment to the function call and suggestions. I didn't want us to get bogged down with a wider discussion about what this is being used for. The lack of context is deliberate!

Comment: @jez I recognise it's just a toy and good practice to focus the question - though not all responses realise that.
But obviously it's hard to give any wider advice. At volumes like that you probably want some kind of storage system (e.g. database). But you could just write them out to a file. What sounds big in RAM is small in files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only counting characters, but `std::string` is not just characters. On my platform, `sizeof(std::string)` is 32. That's about 9GiB for an array of zero-length strings, before you start adding any characters.

If a string is short, most implementations keep the characters inside those 32 bytes to avoid allocations. But your strings are longer than that, so the characters are allocated on the free store. Add 12 GiB worth of characters, and you are well out of memory.

Comment: Yes, thank you! The implication of this is that the code is fine, I just need more memory. Simply setting a bigger page file size solves the problem. I thought the 16GB I was giving it would have been enough, but it runs fine with 32GB. Case closed :)